# Gather list of @PlanningEntity or @PlanningVariable when evaluating constrains in filter()

Tags: java, optaplanner

I would like to gather a list of @PlanningEntity or @PlanningVariable in order to use it in a constraint.  I have an airline problem where I have a Seat and it gets assigned a Passenger based on a preference and weight (basically a Bid).  I want the top passengers with highest Bids assigned to be rewarded for their assigned Seat.

I have tried groupBy but it returns a list() with one value, the current Passenger

```
constraintFactory
            .forEach(Passenger.class)
            .groupBy(Function.identity(), ConstraintCollectors.toList())
            .join(Seat.class, Joiners.equal( (pass, passList) -> pass, Seat::getPassanger))
            
            //for each passenger for each seat make sure the passenger was the highest bid
            .filter((pass, passList, seat) -> {... }
```

In my example I want the passList to be the full list of Passengers.  I'm not sure if this even possible with the API.  I can always "hack" it and get the list other ways in my application.  Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a misunderstanding of how `groupBy(...)` works. The first argument specifies the group key, and the second argument is the function that should be used on all members of the group. Since the first argument is `Passenger`, and the stream contains nothing but `Passenger`, each group will have exactly one member (that one `Passenger` instance), and therefore so will the list.

What you're trying to do is:

```
constraintFactory
    .forEach(Passenger.class)
    .groupBy(ConstraintCollectors.toList())
```

This way, there is only one group, and that group contains all of the `Passenger` instances. However, I want to stress that *you should not do this either*.

The power (and speed) of Constraint Streams comes from the fact that it can process data incrementally. When a `Passenger` changes, we know we should only re-evaluate those constraints where the `Passenger` class is involved, and specifically where the given instance of `Passenger` is involved. Therefore, instead of processing possibly thousands, millions of passengers, we will only process those that were added, removed, or changed.

However, when you collect to a list, all of that goes away - from that moment  on, all we have is a list. And none of the operations on the contents of that list will happen incrementally. In fact, your own processing functions will be written so that you operate on the list, and not on the individual changed elements. Therefore, doing something like this *kills your performance*.

I understand why people do this. Imperative programming, and more importantly imperative *thinking*, is easier. Thinking in Constraint Streams is harder, and takes some getting used to. Still, I advise you to try to think about doing this in an incremental way, and if you can't figure it out, define your constraint precisely in another StackOverflow question, and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Amazing answer.  I will try to rethink my problem.  Thanks

Comment: Lukáš will the performance impact be that bad even when I consider that a Passenger has Bids (preferences) and these are basically static.  I will always have the same amount of both, but it's the Seat assignment that changes and reflected in the score.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors. For hundreds of entities, it may not matter; for millions, it will be a killer. You can prototype it like this and if, in the end, you have low score calculation speeds, you know what you must change.